# `Integer` vs `Int64` vs `Word64`

Tags: haskell, integer

I have some data which can be represented by an unsigned `Integral` type and its biggest value requires 52 bits. AFAIK only `Integer`, `Int64` and `Word64` satisfy these requirements.

All the information I could find out about those types was that `Integer` is signed and has a floating unlimited bit-size, `Int64` and `Word64` are fixed and signed and unsigned respectively. What I coudn't find out was the information on the actual implementation of those types:

1. How many bits will a 52-bit value actually occupy if stored as an `Integer`?
2. Am I correct that `Int64` and `Word64` allow you to store a 64-bit data and weigh exactly 64 bits for any value?
3. Are any of those types more performant or preferrable for any other reasons than size, e.g. native code implementations or direct processor instructions-related optimizations?
4. And just in case: which one would you recommend for storing a 52-bit value in an application extremely sensitive in terms of performance?

Comment: Note: On 32-bit systems (concerning GHC, Windows is 32 bits, even 64 bit Windows), most operations on `Int64` or `Word64` (and the unboxed variants) are implemented as foreign calls to C functions. That means that on 32-bit systems, using `Integer` has a realistic chance of being faster than the fixed-width 64-bits (+ constructor) types. If enough of the values actually fit in 32 bits, that's even likely to happen.

Comment: Is calling out to GMP really cheaper than a normal FFI call? It does indeed make sense if most of the values fit into 32 bits, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer A very useful note, Daniel. I'll definitely have to take this into consideration. Thank you! Actually, as you might have guessed my system will have a <=32-bit value ~62% of the time (32/52). :)

Comment: @ehird The GMP calls are `foreign import prim`, the `Int/Word64` calls are `foreign import ccall unsafe`. I don't know what difference that makes, but `prim` calls are a bit cheaper. However, the big thing is when you stay within `Int` range, then there's no foreign call for `Integer` at all.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, indeed; sounds like Integer is the way to go on 32-bit.

Comment: @Nikita At around 60%, I expect `Int64/Word64` to be a bit faster than `Integer`, though the call to GMP is a bit cheaper than a generic unsafe ccall, the overhead of GMP representation can easily cost more. But I'm only making somewhat educated guesses here, measure to find out what's faster for your case.

Comment: @ehird If it were so easy. Whether `Integer` is faster or slower than `Int64` on 32-bits depends _very much_ on what you are doing and how many of your values fit into `Int`.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov That glib "(32/52)" statistic worries me. If your numbers are distributed uniformly, significantly more than 32/52 of them will have one of their top 20 bits turned on: there's a 1 in 2^20 chance that any given set of 20 bits are all off. For your statistic to make sense, the distribution of which is the first on bit would have to be uniform -- a very atypical distribution, I think.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yeah you're right but in the other aspect. You reminded me to take into account that my program will mostly involve working with random bitsets of size 5 (numbers with 5 bits equal to 1), which leads to correction of the equation to `(32/52)^5` which leaves us with ~9% chance for having a value fitting in 32-bit and `Int64` as a definite winner.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> How many bits will a 52-bit value actually occupy if stored as an `Integer`?

This is implementation-dependent. With GHC, values that fit inside a machine word are stored directly in a constructor of `Integer`, so if you're on a 64-bit machine, it should take the same amount of space as an Int. This corresponds to the `S#` constructor of `Integer`:

```
data Integer = S# Int#
             | J# Int# ByteArray#
```

Larger values (i.e. those represented with `J#`) are stored with [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

> Am I correct that `Int64` and `Word64` allow you to store a 64-bit data and weigh exactly 64 bits for any value?

Not quite — they're *boxed*. An `Int64` is actually a pointer to either an unevaluated thunk or a one-word pointer to an *info table* plus a 64-bit integer value. (See the [GHC commentary](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects) for more information.)

If you really want something that's guaranteed to be 64 bits, no exceptions, then you can use an unboxed type like `Int64#`, but I would strongly recommend profiling first; unboxed values are quite painful to use. For instance, you can't use unboxed types as arguments to type constructors, so you can't have a list of `Int64#`s. You also have to use operations specific to unboxed integers. And, of course, all of this is extremely GHC-specific.

If you're looking to store a lot of 52-bit integers, you might want to use [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) or [repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) (built on vector, with fancy things like automatic parallelism); they store the values unboxed under the hood, but let you work with them in boxed form. (Of course, each individual value you take out will be boxed.)

> Are any of those types more performant or preferrable for any other reasons than size, e.g. native code implementations or direct processor instructions-related optimizations?

Yes; using `Integer` incurs a branch for every operation, since it has to distinguish the machine-word and bignum cases; and, of course, it has to handle overflow. Fixed-size integral types avoid this overhead.

> And just in case: which one would you recommend for storing a 52-bit value in an application extremely sensitive in terms of performance?

If you're using a 64-bit machine: `Int64` or, if you must, `Int64#`.

If you're using a 32-bit machine: Probably `Integer`, since on 32-bit `Int64` is emulated with FFI calls to GHC functions that are probably not very highly optimised, but I'd try both and benchmark it. With `Integer`, you'll get the best performance on small integers, and GMP is heavily-optimised, so it'll probably do better on the larger ones than you might think.

You could select between `Int64` and `Integer` at compile-time using the C preprocessor (enabled with `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}`); I think it would be easy to get Cabal to control a `#define` based on the word width of the target architecture. Beware, of course, that they are not the same; you will have to be careful to avoid "overflows" in the `Integer` code, and e.g. `Int64` is an instance of `Bounded` but `Integer` is not. It might be simplest to just target a single word width (and thus type) for performance and live with the slower performance on the other.

I would suggest creating your own `Int52` type as a `newtype` wrapper over `Int64`, or a `Word52` wrapper over `Word64` — just pick whichever matches your data better, there should be no performance impact; if it's just arbitrary bits I'd go with `Int64`, just because `Int` is more common than `Word`.

You can define all the instances to handle wrapping automatically (try `:info Int64` in GHCi to find out which instances you'll want to define), and provide "unsafe" operations that just apply directly under the `newtype` for performance-critical situations where you know there won't be any overflow.

Then, if you don't export the `newtype` constructor, you can always swap the implementation of `Int52` later, without changing any of the rest of your code. Don't worry about the overhead of a separate type — the runtime representation of a `newtype` is completely identical to the underlying type; they only exist at compile-time.

Comment: I've gained a lot of useful information from your answer, thanks! I still have some questions though:
1. I'm not sure I understood you correctly: by avoiding a branch of extra operations did you imply rejecting `Integer`?
2. Do you believe that using fixed-length implementations will be more performant than `Integer` in all cases?
3. Isn't the [although questionable] economy of ~10 free bits worth something?
4. Daniel Fischer in comment to my question suggested to use `Integer` for better performance in 32-bit mode - what do you think about that?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: I've expanded my answer to answer these. I don't quite understand #3, though — no value occupies less than a full machine word, and GMP allocates space for the bignums in machine words too.

Comment: Thank you for the "machine word" comment. As embarassing as it is but being a self-educated programmer I didn't know that. I have one last question left: why did you prefer Int64 over Word64?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: I've updated my answer again to answer that and give some additional suggestions :)

Comment: Great! Thanks! Good point on `newtype`, but I think I'll just go with a simple `type` alias over `Int64`.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: Unfortunately, that will mean that you can't define instances for any classes — so you'll be unable to use any generic code (e.g. working on any `Bounded`) with `Int52`, and you'll have to take special care to always use your own versions of every operation. The `newtype` wrapper is a bit of up-front effort, but will simplify things a lot in the long run; you can still use numeric literals, etc. thanks to Haskell's polymorphic literals.